# mapquest map not following user location

Tags: android, mapquest

I'm developing a android navigation app with mapquest. The marker representing my location on the map, gets out of the map eventually as I move. Is there a way to make the map follow my location as I move??

I tried "map.getController().animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation())" inside onLocationChanged(). But the map is starting to twitch every instant

Thanks 
Gokul

Answer (score 0):

If you tell the map to animate every time you get a location update, it often starts new animations while the old ones are still playing. This is probably the cause of the twitchy behavior you see. Instead of animating, you could move directly to the new location. The downside is that the map will not smoothly scroll to the new location, it will just be there instantly. You can accomplish this with

```
// replace LAT and LNG with the lat and lng values from your current location
map.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(LAT, LNG));
```

Comment: but i want a smooth or something like that traversal when i move. i ve set my setclickable as false

Comment: That's a pretty tough problem to solve. There is no reliable way to know how long before the next location update comes in, which means there is no good way to tell the code how long the animation should last. I don't think the SDK exposes enough details for you do solve this problem without implementing your own version of map movement. Possible solutions might include queuing animations (so the next one doesn't start until the previous one completes) or canceling any animation that is in progress when a new one comes in.

Answer (score 0):

The MyLocationOverlay has an api call for this:

```java
mMyLocationOverlay.setFollowing(true);
```